# Change css to inline or something support on mail

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I am writing CSS for my UI, but I am facing with stuck, please lets me know the css code that could alternative to it

here is my current css (using grid)

```css
.list, .item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.list {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(268px, 1fr));
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class='list'>
  <div class='item'>
    left
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    right
  </div>
</div>
<div class='list'>
  <div class='item'>
    center
  </div>
</div>
```

I try to using flex by the code (using flex)

```css
.list, .item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.list {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='list'>
  <div class='item'>
    left
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    right
  </div>
</div>
<div class='list'>
  <div class='item'>
    center
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, I change all to inline CSS, but when send to Gmail, it seems mail delete some attribute, then my layout break

[image]

please help me this

Comment: Hello, so you sent your mail with flex or grid

Comment: @rrr63, I have tried both grid and flex, but it's still didn't work. Finally, I added a new class .has-1-item for parent div, and set width for case has/no-has class .has-1-item